# How do you change the Docker container TZ in spring?

Tags: java, spring, docker, timezone

I am using `frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8` base image as recommended by spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
ADD gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

I am running the image with `-e TZ=/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris`

I am setting the env `TZ` but this doesn't change the TimeZone in my container.

How do you change the timezone for this image?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alpine Linux does not install timezone files by default to minimize the size of the Docker image.

You need to explicitly install the `tzdata` package and copy the zoneinfo file according to the timezone you want to set.

An example for `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim

RUN apk --update add tzdata && \
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris /etc/localtime && \
    apk del tzdata && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

Build the image:

```
$ docker build -t tztest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
 ---> 00d8610f052e
Step 2 : RUN apk --update add tzdata &&     cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris /etc/localtime &&     apk del tzdata &&     rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
 ---> Running in 5b6a014fdaf3
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/1) Installing tzdata (2016i-r0)
Executing busybox-1.25.1-r0.trigger
OK: 14 MiB in 15 packages
(1/1) Purging tzdata (2016i-r0)
Executing busybox-1.25.1-r0.trigger
OK: 10 MiB in 14 packages
 ---> 6c379ddd4186
Removing intermediate container 5b6a014fdaf3
Successfully built 6c379ddd4186
```

Check `date` of the container:

```
$ docker run -it --rm tztest date
Thu Mar  9 16:34:54 CET 2017
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to set timzone at runtime not on build, install the `tzdata` package and do not delete on build:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim

RUN apk --no-cache add tzdata
```

Build the image:

```
$ docker build -t tztest .
```

And then, you can set environment variable `TZ` at runtime:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -e TZ="Europe/Paris" tztest date
Fri Mar 10 01:59:27 CET 2017
```

Comment: I guess it is be possible to set an ENV to use inside the Dockerfile?

Comment: I've added an example for setting timezone at runtime not on build. Try it.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this ten more times. I've been searching all afternoon for this, and most of the solutions a search turns up are for ubuntu, completely different, and don't work in Alpine.